# How to launch python script as a windows Services

Tags: python, services, windows-services

Using python 2.7 and windows 7. I have a python file(.py). I want to launch this script as a windows services, i.e. this code will keep on running from start to end and never terminate.

I can convert .py file into an exe using **py2exe**. How to launch this and how the code flow works in services. Is it starts from line one to continue to last line, and then again starts from line one of code.

Comment: See this [thread][1] on stackoverflow


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-how

Comment: I am getting error as [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333283/error-service-instance-has-no-attribute-svcdorun)

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to use the: NSSM - the Non-Sucking Service Manager:

1. Download on https://nssm.cc/download
2. Install the Python program as a service: Win prompt as admin

   ```
   c:>nssm.exe install WinService
   ```
3. In NSSM's console:

   ```
   path: C:\Python27\Python27.exe
   Startup directory: C:\Python27
   Arguments: c:\WinService.py
   ```
4. Check the created services on services.msc

Answer (score 1):

Sorry with my current level in superuser I can't add a comment like my first answer.

Download the required lib with the right version of Python and Windows:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

To install the service, just type:

```
<Your python Path>\python.exe "Path to your script".py install
```

I have tested the script in the link you gave me and it's working correctly in my computer.

If you want to delete the service, just type in cmd (as admin):

```
sc delete "Service Name"
```